# RabbitMQ Open Channel e return message for Domain .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq

I am working with RabbitMQ and would like to make the following configuration.

Open a channel, receive the information and return to my BLL to deal with, but keep this channel open.

For this I have a service class where I have the methods of publisher and consumer and my bll consumes those methods.

My biggest problem is in the automatic ACK, I would like to be able to control it from my bll, but I would need the channel instance that I created in my service.

Is there any right way to do this?

Can I return the instance along with the message?

```
public Task<List<string>> ConsumerRabbitMQ(string queeue, bool isWork)
{
    try
    {
        var message = new List<string>();
        
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: queeue,
                                 durable: false,
                                 exclusive: false,
                                 autoDelete: false,
                                 arguments: null);

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
           
            consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var body = ea.Body.Span;
                    message.Add(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body));

                    channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var ff = channel;
                    CreateConnection();
                 
                    channel.BasicNack(ea.DeliveryTag, false, true);
                }
            };

            channel.BasicConsume(queue: queeue,
                                 autoAck: false,
                                 consumer: consumer);

           
        }                           

        return Task.FromResult(message);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;

        throw;
    }
}
```

This is my consumer class, I store in a list all the items in the queue and give a return at the end to my BLL, am I doing it the right way?